# Laravel: Request regresa pagina vacía

Tags: php, laravel-5

Tengo una vista que me redirige a un método especial de un controlador

```
    {{  Form::model($recibo, array('action'=>'ReciboController@vender')) }}
```

El método tiene un request especial

```
    public function vender(ReciboFormRequest $request){
    ...
    return view('recibo.index', ['recibos' => $recibos]);
    }
```

Cuando el request está bien no me causa problema y avanza a la otra página, pero si falta algún dato me regresa una pantalla en blanco en la misma URL donde está el formulario. Uso Laravel 5.3

Comment: Por favor comparte el código del Request personalizado.

Comment: Pasa la respuesta al router y del router al controller.

Answer (score 0):

Cuando creas un request especial, puede que estes sobre escribiendo el método que muestra los errores, ya que, laravel por defecto te muestra los campos inválidos, podría ayudar si muestras archivo ReciboFormRequest.
Saludos!

Comment: Esto es más un comentario que una respuesta.

Comment: ¿cuál es el método que muestra los errores?

Comment: El request no tiene nada de especial, la única regla que tiene es "required" y el authorize regresa true. Creo que tiene que ver con que la ruta que te lleva al view donde está el form es POST; creo el request al fallar lo regresa como GET y es ahí donde está el error.